How can I straighten this crimp in an aluminum shovel?
Back and front view of the bend.
I see two issues: unbending the kink without tearing, and reinforcing it so it doesn’t break again.
Does aluminum need to be heated?



Buy a steel shovel.

Repairing seems like an exercise in futility.  Take it to a scrapper.

You have a good handle.  Store that for the day you find a shovel with a busted handle but a good blade.

If you find a method to heat the aluminum, it's likely you'll go from "cold" to melted in the blink of an eye. Heating aluminum generates oxides on the surface, allowing the metal underneath to heat without a visual indicator. One moment it's solid, the next moment, it's a puddle.
Aluminum also suffers fatigue failure much faster than steel does, so you may get away with a single bend to return to the original shape or near enough to serve as a shovel.
Note that the failure mode is that the sides of the tubing that make up the intersection between the handle portion of the tubing and the blade portion of the tubing has spread apart. You may have some success using a strong c-clamp to compress the spread portion, or if you have access to a strong bench vise, the same application of force could be useful.
Other bending forces will have to be applied during this process, such as bending the handle while securing the blade.
Once you have reached an acceptable position, consider to drill a hole closer to the blade, still in the tubing area, to assist to keep the edges "closed" and more rigid. I would also mix up a good bit of some reinforced epoxy or a lot of tubes of JB Weld™ and fill the opening, although the bolt is going to be the primary aid, I believe.

A few melted beer cans might help.

yes, that might be a good filler

Aluminium is a very good conductor of heat (thus spreading it out quickly), and melts at about 660°C.  Heating to 300°C is plenty for bending.  You can do that with a heat gun having a lower exhaust temperature than the melting point, thus making melting impossible, though I prefer a small butane blowtorch on smaller pieces
